# Click on Checkbox all users can move in another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my js file i have to dis when i click on select all , all the users can move in the side where remove all places and whenclick on remove all , all the users can move in where select all placed......

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Uncheck each checkbox on body load
    $('#all_users .close_img').each(function () {
        this.checked = false;
    });
    $('#selected_users .close_img').each(function () {
        this.checked = false;
    });
    $('#all_users .close_img').click(function () {
        var userid = $(this).attr('uid');
        $('#user' + userid).toggleClass('innertxt_bg');
    });
    $('#selected_users .close_img').click(function () {
        var userid = $(this).attr('uid');
        $('#user' + userid).toggleClass('innertxt_bg');
    });
    $(".slider_user_out2").click(function () {
        var users = $('#selected_users .innertxt2').size();
        var selected_users = $('#all_users .innertxt_bg').size();
        if (users + selected_users > 15) {
            alert('You can only chose maximum 15 users.');
            return;
        }
        $('#all_users .innertxt_bg').each(function () {
            var user_id = $(this).attr('userid');
            $('#select' + user_id).each(function () {
                this.checked = false;
            });
            var user_clone = $(this).clone(true);
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt');
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt_bg');
            $(user_clone).addClass('innertxt2');
            $('#selected_users').append(user_clone);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $(".close_img").click(function () {
        $('#selected_users .innertxt_bg').each(function () {
            var user_id = $(this).attr('userid');
            $('#select' + user_id).each(function () {
                this.checked = false;
            });
            var user_clone = $(this).clone(true);
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt2');
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt_bg');
            $(user_clone).addClass('innertxt');
            $('#all_users').append(user_clone);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('#view').click(function () {
        var users = '';
        $('#selected_users .innertxt2').each(function () {
            var user_id = $(this).attr('userid');
            if (users == '') users += user_id;
            else users += ',' + user_id;
        });
        alert(users);
    });
});
$('.styled1').click(function () {
    $('#all_users').remove();
});
$('.styled2').click(function () {
    $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt2');
    $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt_bg');
    $(user_clone).addClass('innertxt');
});
```

this is my html file i have to dis when i click on select all , all the users can move in the side where remove all places and whenclick on remove all , all the users can move in where select all placed......

```
<div id="view3">
    <div class="editors_inn">
        <div class="add_more_btn">  <a href="javascript:" onClick="toggleVisibility();">Add Members<span>+</span></a>

        </div>
        <div id="selected_users">
            <div class="stylist_check" uid="userid">
                <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="checkbox" class="styled2" />Remove all</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="view4">
    <div class="editors_inn">
        <div class="add_more_btn">  <a href="#" onClick="toggleVisibility();">Add Members<span>+</span></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="view5">
    <div class="editors_inn">
        <div class="add_more_btn">  <a href="#" onClick="toggleVisibility();">Add Members<span>+</span></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="add_more_btn2"> <a href="javascript:;" onClick="addAnswer(); return false;">Add More Filters<span>+</span></a>

</div>
<div class="stylist_check">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="checkbox" class="styled1" />Select all</div>
<!--all-user-->
<div id="all_users">
    <div id="user1" userid="1" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img " uid="1"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user2" userid="2" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>John peter </span>
                <div class="close_img" uid="2"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user3" userid="3" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Heffan</span>
                <div class="close_img" uid="3"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user4" userid="4" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img" uid="4"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user5" userid="5" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img" uid="5"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user6" userid="6" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img" uid="6"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user7" userid="7" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img" uid="7"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user8" userid="8" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img" uid="8"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user9" userid="9" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img" uid="9"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user10" userid="10" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img" uid="10"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user11" userid="11" class="editors_user">
        <div class="slider_user_out2">
            <div class="edit_user_left">
                <img src="images/icon_user4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="edit_user_right"><span>Ivan Schnizer</span> 
                <div class="close_img" uid="11"><a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--all-user_end-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- <div id="sortable"></div>-->
    <h2 class="heading_play">My Playlist</h2>

<ol class="droppable">
    <li>
        <div class="drop1 buttons2" id="buttons2">
            <!--<div class=" sortable"></div>--></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </li>
</ol>
<!--<div class="pro_iframe"><iframe src="index_iframe.html" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></div></iframe>-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- scroll-->
<!--pop_html-->
<div class="md-modal md-effect-8" id="modal-8">
    <div class="md-content">
            <h3>Activity</h3>

        <div>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
                1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
                make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
                Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
                like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <button class="md-close">Close me!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
<!--pop_html-->
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">             </script>-->
<script>
    !window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))
</script>
<!-- custom scrollbars plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
                autoHideScrollbar: true,
                scrollButtons: {
                    enable: true
                }
            });
            $("#content_2").mCustomScrollbar({
                autoHideScrollbar: true,
                scrollButtons: {
                    enable: true
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<!--scroll_end-->
<!--pop_window-->
<script src="js/pop/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/pop/modalEffects.js"></script>
<script>
    // this is important for IEs
    var polyfilter_scriptpath = '/js/';
</script>
<script src="js/pop/cssParser.js"></script>
<script src="js/pop/css-filters-polyfill.js"></script>
<!--pop_window-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/function.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you put your code into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what you're trying to achieve.  I tried a quick copy & paste but as you have js in the html and mismatched html tags it didn't work.

Comment: if i put into jsfiddle can u do something

Comment: If you put in in JSFiddle it will be easier to see what the problem is